# symbol cannot be found java

Tags: java

I am just starting to learn some java guyz this was my first class to create and am stuck i keep getting an error like symbol not found when  i try to compile the class NameTest.java

classes.java

```
 public class classes
     {
     // defining classes 
     public class Name
     {
       //class members or variables or fields
        private String first;
        private String middle;
        private String last;    
        //constructor methods
        public Name(String f, String m, String l)
        {
            // assigning  letters
            first = f;
            middle = m;
            last = l;
        }
        //default constructor has no parameters
        public Name()
        {
            first = "";
            middle = "";
            last = "";
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return first + " " + middle + " " + last;
        }
        /* class methods
        method name(public) method  return type string and method name displayName
        methods r like operations in a class */
        public String displayName()
        {
         return first + " " + middle + " " + last;
        }
     public String getInitials()
      {
          //substring for getting a sub sting in a string
          //(0,1) 0 is for the position for the character in a sting 
          // 1 is the number of characters to b  pulled from a substring
         return first.substring(0,1) + middle.substring(0,1) + last.substring(0,1);

      }
     }
        public static void main(String[] args)
      {

      }
    }
```

NameTest.java

```
public class NameTest
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     //instantiation
      Name myName = new Name("smart", "daniel", "zulu");
      Name yourName = new Name("daniel", "Zulu");
      Name aName = new Name("Zulu");
      System.out.println("myName: " + myName.toString());
  }
}
```

i need some assistance on how to solve the error

Comment: If you need help on a particular error, please post the complete error message. That way, we have more information.

Comment: What symbol? we have guess it for you?

Comment: Constructor `new Name("daniel", "Zulu")`  and `new Name("Zulu") `are not defined.

Comment: I see only two constructors where is the one-argument and two-argument constructors you used for creating `new Name("Zulu")` and `new Name("daniel", "Zulu")` respectively?

Comment: construct in this way `classes.Name myName = new classes.Name("smart", "daniel", "zulu");` in your case but actually you don't require outer class at all.

Comment: Inner classes can be useful but usually 1 file==1 class

Comment: The way you've created `Name` as an inner class inside a class called `classes` is weird.  You should just create `Name` as a top level class

Comment: @Braj don't think `new classes.Name(...)` will work because `Name` isn't `static`

Comment: @NickHolt it works. Test it.

Comment: @AntonH the code is explicit to spot the errors.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I get an error saying "'classes' is not an enclosing class"

Comment: @NickHolt which makes me wonder how did you copy/paste/adapted the code. I did it and worked with no problems.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza your code is subtly different in that you've created an instance of `classes`, then you're creating new `Name`s from there.  @Braj was saying to do `new classes.Name(...)` - mystery solved :-)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance everyone ,  i  dropped classes and named it Name then everything was solved  and also removed public class classes after that it just worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Name` is an inner class of `classes`, so you cannot directly access to `Name` unless you have an object reference of `classes`.

To simply fix your current code, rewrite the code in `NameTest` to this:

```
classes c = new classes();
classes.Name myName = c.new Name("smart", "daniel", "zulu");
classes.Name yourName = c.new Name("daniel", "Zulu");
classes.Name aName = c.new Name("Zulu");
System.out.println("myName: " + myName.toString());
```

The better option is to move the `Name` classes as a top class, then the code will compile as expected.

```
//rename classes.java file to Name.java as well
//public class classes
//     {
     // defining classes 
     public class Name
     {
     }
//}
```

Comment: I used the second option of renaming the file

Answer (score 1):

Best solution : 
Drop the class "classes" on top of your code and make a single file with the name "Name.java" that contains only the class "Name". You can also drop the "static main()" method in the class "Name".

Alternatively you can change the code :

```
new Name()
```

to

```
new classes.new Name()
```

since "Name" is a innerclass of the class "Classes"

EDIT : Corrected the code based on the comments of  Luiggi Mendoza. Thanks for the correction

Comment: It should be `new classes().new Name();`, otherwise it doesn't compile.

Comment: See the discussion between me and @LuiggiMendoza in the comments of the question - you can't do `new classes.Name()` because `Name` isn't a static inner class.  You have to first create an instance of `classes` as @LuiggiMendoza has in his answer.